# Cucumber 7 + TestNG - Dynamic tags manipulation before test run start

Tags: java, testing, cucumber, testng

I use TestNG and Cucumber in my project.

Used versions:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

All works fine, but I need to make some dynamic tags manipulation before test run start.
To be more specific - I need to add additional filter tag expressions based on some conditions of environment.

Current implementation is `AbstractTestNGCucumberTests` class with a `TestNGCucumberRunner` field.

The place where I need to change/add some lines of code is in the constructor of `TestNGCucumberRunner` class, since the runner initializes and starts the test run right there.

Problem is that almost all classes in *cucumber-testng* dependency are not `public` and `final`. So I cannot extend classes and override some logic.

Only way I see is to duplicate all the classes in dependency to my source folder what is a weird and dumb idea.

Is there any tips how can I achieve my goal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When extending `AbstractTestNGCucumberTests` you can filter the output from `scenarios()`

```
public class RunCucumberTest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    @Override
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        Object[][] scenarios = super.scenarios();
        // Do filtering here
        return scenarios;
    }

}
```

Because the data provider is used to invoke the test methode you can safely cast the first array element to `PickleWrapper` and use the `pickleWrapper.getPickle().get tags()` to access the tags.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

This solution above is really good. It put me on the right track. I didn't understand how to overwrite the tags during run time. But I wanted the whole filtering thing work with usual 'and' 'or' 'not' expressions of cucumber tag and also as simple as passing multiple tags separated by comma.

So, after whole day of digging around the cucumber classes starting from AbstractTestNGCucumberTests, I understood how exactly tags are handled. Then, I found the perfect solution. Here is the complete code.

```
/**
 * This runner is a hybrid runner which can run normally as local runner with Cucumber Options or run with tags variable passed from Pipeline tools or from any other sources
 * <br></br>
 * This runner works with either of them or both combined. Let's say You have passed '@smoke' tag in @CucumberOptions annotation which have 100 scenarios, then additionally you can also pass a runtime tag "@Login" and filter again.
 */
@CucumberOptions( features = "src/test/resources/features/",
                  glue = { "stepDefinitions", "hooks" },
                  plugin = { "pretty", "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:" },
                  tags = "" )       //Pass tags here as usual
public class CucumberRunnerTest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests
{

    @DataProvider
    @Override
    public Object[][] scenarios()
    {
        Object[][] scenarios = super.scenarios();

        String dynamicTags = System.getenv("tags");   //passed from Pipeline 
        //Or add any other sources you want to get the tags from

        if ( dynamicTags != null && !dynamicTags.equals("") ) return (Arrays.stream(scenarios).filter(scenario -> TagExpressionParser.parse(dynamicTags).evaluate((( PickleWrapper ) scenario[0]).getPickle().getTags())).collect(Collectors.toList())).toArray(new Object[0][0]);
        else return scenarios;
    }
}
```

I narrowed it down to one simple line of TagExpression but it took me hours to find these and understand from so many different classes.

Try this once, hope it helps.